# void* casting in 2 ways: (Sometype_t*)(*ptr) vs. *((Sometype_t**)ptr), why does only the second work?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

this may be a silly question but I have struggled to find an explanation (mostly due to the fact that I have trouble formulating this question).

So I have a `void* pointer` which actually is a `void** double-pointer` when passed to the function, let's call it `ptr`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void aFunction(void* ptr);

typedef struct Type_ {
    char something[10];
} Type_t;

int main() {
    void* s = malloc(sizeof (Type_t));
    void** d = &s;

    aFunction(d);

    return (0);
}

void aFunction(void* ptr) {
    //Option 1
    Type_t* o1 = (Type_t*) (*ptr);

    //Option 2
    Type_t* o2 = *((Type_t**) ptr);
}
```

Option 1 doesn't work (it is not compiling and NetBeans or rather the GNU compiler tells me that this is not how you use void pointers) but Option 2 does.

I can not figure out why the first one doesn't work. In my opinion it should go as follows
1. with `*ptr` we get the `void*`
2. the `void*` is casted to `Type_t*`

Can someone explain the technicality here?

Edit:

Sorry, I miswrote this question first. My actual problem only exists when the parameter of the function is void* and void** is passed.

Comment: Is this C, or C++? You've double-tagged, but the rules are different. For C, you wouldn't need and shouldn't use any cast at all. For C++, recommended practise is to use a different cast syntax to protect yourself from accidental nonsense casts. Please get rid of one of those tags. And what specifically doesn't work with what you first tried?

Comment: *"but that doesn't work"* - You don't show real, full code. When I try the simplest interpretation of that line with the cast, then everything works perfectly even in C++:  `int main() { void** ptr = nullptr; using Type_t = int; Type_t* a = (Type_t*) (*ptr); }` It compiles and runs without undefined behaviour, crashes or any other bad things. Moral of the story: **"doesn't work" is not an acceptable problem description.**

Comment: On second thought, derefencing the `nullptr` is undefined behaviour, of course (those nasty double pointers cause endless parsing problems in my brain). Perhaps this is what you meant?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Sorry for that, I created an example. Also I used the recommended tag C++ by mistake, it is only C.

Comment: @hvd I fixed the initial question, I hope it is easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Take the version that works first:

```
void aFunction(void** ptr) {
    //Option 1
    Type_t* o1 = (Type_t*) (*ptr);

    //Option 2
    Type_t* o2 = *((Type_t**) ptr);
}
```

Note that I've changed `ptr` to `void**`.

Option 1 reads the value pointed to by `ptr`. It then converts that value to `Type_t*`. It is equivalent to `Type_t* o1 = *ptr;` and if possible should be written in this form.

Option 2 tells the compiler that `ptr` doesn't really point to a `void*`, but to a `Type_t*`, and then reads that value.

Now change it to what doesn't work, by changing `ptr` back to `void*`:

Option 1 cannot read the value pointed to by `ptr`, because it doesn't know what kind of value it is dealing with. Since it isn't able to read a value, it then cannot convert it to `Type_t*`.

Option 2 tells the compiler that `ptr` points to a `Type_t*`, and then reads that value.

That's why option 1 can't work in this case.

However, beware that telling the compiler that `ptr` points to a `Type_t*` when it doesn't actually point to a `Type_t*` can cause all kinds of hard-to-debug problems, because when you call the function as

```
void* p = 0;
aFunction(&p);
```

the compiler may at some point see "oh, I don't know what `ptr` points to, but the programmer told me it points to a `Type_t*`, so I know it can't point to `p`." And may optimise based on that assumption, for instance by not initialising `p` yet since it has determined that `p` does not get accessed. Or at least not in a way that the compiler allows. If this is how `aFunction` is called, then the correct way of accessing the value of `p` is `Type_t* o1 = *((void**)ptr);`: this tells the compiler that `ptr` really points to a `void*`, which it does. It then dereferences `ptr`, reading a `void*`, and converts that `void*` to a `Type_t*`.

On the other hand, if `ptr` really does point to a `Type_t*`, for instance when calling it as

```
Type_t** p = 0;
aFunction(&p);
```

then telling the compiler that `ptr` really points to a `Type_t*` is entirely correct.

Which approach you should take depends on how you're calling `aFunction`.